# angular.js:13424 Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `delete`

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, dapper

I am trying to delete an object and return an list which does trigger the web api controller method but then get the error

```
Expected response to contain an object but got an array (Request: DELETE



 $scope.deleteProduct = function (productId) {
        productResource.delete({
            id: productId
        }, function (data) {
            $scope.products = data;
        });
    }
```

Resource controller

```
 function productResource($resource) {


    return $resource("/api/products/:id");
   }
```

Web api controller

```
 public IQueryable Delete(int id)
    {
        var repository = new ProductRepository();
        return repository.Delete(id).AsQueryable();

    }
```

And this is the call to the database which returns a list of products.

```
 internal List<Product> Delete(int Id)
    {
        IDbConnection connection;
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Liberty"].ToString()))
        {
            var result = connection.QueryMultiple("DeleteProduct", new{prodId = Id}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            var products = result.Read<Product>().ToList();
            return products;
        }
    }
```

How am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify that the return type of the DELETE operation is an array because that's what your Web API controller returns:

```
function productResource($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/products/:id", { }, {
        'delete': {
            method: 'DELETE',
            isArray: true
        }
    });
}
```